# Force text to overflow in the bottom margin

Tags: margins, koma-script

How can I make, in one particular page, the last two paragraphs overflow into the white space in the bottom margin?

The class is `scrartcl`. I tried adding to the textheight with `\addtolenght{\textheight}{3cm}`, but it did not work.

I also tried using `\usepackage[bottom=1cm]{geometry}`, but this overrides the nice margins calculated by KOMA-Script.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,DIV=11,parskip]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

\kant[1-4]

This paragraph should be on the first page.

An so should be this one.
\end{document}
```

Is there a way to say "these paragraphs must remain in this page and are allowed to overflow"?

Comment: For the record: `\addtolenght{\textheight}{3cm}` needs a corresponding `\addtolenght{\vsize}{3cm}` because `\vsize` is not recalculated when `\textheight` is changed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `\enlargethispage` you can make the specific page larger:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,DIV=11,parskip]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

\kant[1-4]

\enlargethispage{4\baselineskip}
This paragraph should be on the first page.

An so should be this one.

text for next page
\end{document}
```

Comment: I planned to include this suggestion too, but will leave it to good care here.  :)

Comment: @gusbrs I apologise for interfering with your plans :)

Answer (score 4):

You could use a `minipage` with the content you want to force on the same page:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,DIV=11,parskip]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\kant[1-4]

This paragraph should be on the first page.

An so should be this one.
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```